# How can I update a TextField value and have its associated index in an array update as well?

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, swiftui

I am having trouble updating values in an array that are displayed via a for each loop. These values are displayed in a text field.

**The code in question**

```
struct EditItemView: View {

let entity: RecipeEntity
@StateObject var viewModel = ViewModelEdit()
@State var imageToUpload: Data
@StateObject var vm = CoreDataRelationshipViewModel()
@Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
@State var stepInfo: String = ""
@State var textFieldCount: Int = 1
@State var stepNumber: [Int]
@State var recipeName: String = ""
@State var recipeArray: [RecipeStepModel]

var body: some View {
    //some code between here and the problem code
        List {
            ForEach(recipeArray, id: \.id) { index in
                            HStack {
                            CustomTextField(item: index)
                            }
                }.onDelete { (indexSet) in
                    recipeArray.remove(atOffsets: indexSet)
                }
```

CustomTextField I am using that allows me to pass my Identifiable model into a foreach. This can be seen referenced in the for each above as `CustomTextField(item: index)`

```
struct CustomTextField : View {
@State var item : RecipeStepModel

var body : some View {
    Text(String(item.stepNumber) + ".")
    TextField("", text: $item.stepName)
}
```

}

Lastly, here is the model for the array referenced in the last @State variable declared `@State var recipeArray: [RecipeStepModel]`:

```
struct RecipeStepModel: Identifiable {
var id = UUID()
var stepName: String
var stepNumber: Int
```

}

**The Question**

How can I make a change to a textfield in a foreach loop and have its value in `@State var recipeArray: [RecipeStepModel]` be updated accordingly? For example, I edit the first TextField in the for each loop - how can I update index 0 in the array with its new value?

**Additional Information**

I posted a similar question the other day. I was able to get it working with .indices in the for each loop. The version of the question asked here is an attempt at restructuring my code using MVVM. Previous question and answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68323683/update-value-in-textfield-and-have-its-array-index-update-accordingly) - I hope this helps!

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/67950131/14733292

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving the issue by converting `@State var item: RecipeStepModel` in my view model to `@Binding var item: RecipeStepModel`

```
struct CustomTextField : View {
@Binding var item : RecipeStepModel

var body : some View {
    Text(String(item.stepNumber) + ".")
    TextField("", text: $item.stepName)
}
```

Once this change was made, I had to alter the code in my ForEach to pass a binding to the CustomTextField view model. Additionally, I had to change `ForEach(recipeArray, id: \.id)` to `ForEach(recipeArray.indices, id: \.self)` :

```
 List {
            ForEach(recipeArray.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                            HStack {
                            CustomTextField(item: $recipeArray[index]) //<--change made here
                            }
                }.onDelete { (indexSet) in
                    recipeArray.remove(atOffsets: indexSet)
                }
```

I am now able to both successfully delete items from the list, and update items in the array simply by changing the value in the appropriate TextField

Answer (score 1):

You need to follow a architecture like MVVM. Make a model where you have your struct RecipeStepModel and then make a seperate ViewModel to add and delete recipes in your array. You should study the Combine framework in SwiftUI, it is used to get input from textfield and then store it in an array.

Check this tutorial from Peter Freise https://github.com/peterfriese/MakeItSo/tree/firebase-combine/final/MakeItSo/MakeItSo for reference.

Comment: From my understanding, my code does follow the MVVM architecture. The model (RecipeStepModel), the view (EditItemView), and the view model (CustomTextField). I am unclear as to how this will allow me to modify data at a given index. I was able to previously do this by using .indices in the foreach loop (e.g. recipeArray.indices) but since changing to this MVVM pattern I can no longer do that. Thoughts?